# Pointers in C++ difference

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's suppose this code:

```
int a;
int * point;
a = 5;

point = &a; // <-----
```

The line I'm arrowing is the same as...

```
*point = a;
```

... or is there a difference in it?

Comment: they are totally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `point = &a;` makes 'point' point to 'a'.
- `*point = a;` assigns the value of 'a' to whatever 'point' is already
  pointing to.

'point' holds an address. '&' gets an address from a variable.
`point = &a;` gets the address of 'a', and assigns it to the pointer.

'*' deferences a pointer (getting the variable it points to), so `*point = a` assigns the value of 'a' to the dereferenced pointer - that is, whatever variable's address was already stored in the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Completely different.

```
point = &a;
```

means "`point` now contains the address of `a`".

```
*point = a;
```

means "the (currently undefined) area of memory that `point` points to now contains the value of `a`".  That version is likely to crash.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you are dereferencing `point` which may have an invalid address at that point. It would not actually write the value to the location `point` has.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same this:

```
*point = a;
```

requires that `point` already points to valid memory in your current program it would not and therefore would be undefined behavior. while this line:

```
point = &a;
```

will assign to `point` the address of an existing object.

Answer (score 0):

The first line assigns the address of a (`&a`) to pointer.

The second line assigns the value of a to the memory block pointed to, by pointer (`*pointer`).

To note: If the pointer doesn't point to the address of a variable in scope, or to an address dynamically allocated, you cause a memory corruption in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this

```
*point = a;
```

may crash, because you haven't allocated a memory to which `point` would be pointing. It's also not pointing to say a stack variable- in which case it would change value of that stack variable to `a`.

In other words, `point` is not pointing to anything, and you are trying to set value of that non existing 'object'.